# Triggered web job not scheduled to run

Tags: azure-webjobs

Our azure website contains a couple of web jobs (say `job1` & `job2`) triggered by a cron expression in `settings.job` file.

```
{
    "schedule": "0 * * * * *"
}
```

Every now and then `job2` stops getting scheduled. This website has 'Always On' turned on. When looking at the portal, last runtime of `job2` is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`. And looking at the scheduler logs for both `job1` and `job2` we find that `job1` has messages like below:

```
[10/19/2015 19:19:00 > 846c07: SYS INFO] WebJob invoked
[10/19/2015 19:19:00 > 846c07: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:59.2588341
[10/19/2015 19:19:00 > a033a5: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:59.9580454
```

Where as `WebJob invoked` message is missing from `job2` logs. That indicates the job is not invoked. Usually the problem disappears if I hit the `Run once` button in the portal against the job, but the issue seems repeating. What's the best way to troubleshoot or prevent such an issue.

Comment: Are you trying to run your WebJobs every 0 seconds? If so, why not run a continuous WebJob?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Its running every minute. I referred this article to get the cron expression : http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.VkOWgbuFMaV. This runs every minute at the 0th second of the minute.

Comment: No worries. You're doing the right thing. One interesting thing is that a new Job won't be started if the existing Job is still running. That may be what you're experiencing.

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT - we did not find any instances of the job running as well.

Comment: Are they using the same settings.json?